# reading web.xml init-params from client gwt

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I have a gwt appengine app that I am building. It has a web.xml file with some init-params in it. On the client side I am using a java class with an 'onLoad()' method. This is a plain 'EntryPoint'. I would like to read those init-params from the web.xml file when the page is loading. I know I can read them from the server side using `getServletConfig().getInitParameter("string")` but what I want to do is to read that init-param from the client side. Is there a simple way? Everything I read tells about doing this from a Servlet. Any help would be appretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are client side and you want information which are server side, so you need to use a technology to do so ,the servlet is the one that will allow you to collect information and send back the result to you client which will be processing it asynchrously.

Comment: ok. I thought a copy of the web.xml file was somehow available on the client side too. I have a couple of rpc calls, so that is not the issue, I just thought that the xml would be easily readable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch those values from Server ( servlet ) by either GWT-RPC or GWT JSON

`GWT JSON Turorial` - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/JSON

`GWT RPC Tutorial` - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC

You can find tutorial examples in the sample folder of the [GWT zip files](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/files/gwt-2.5.0.zip).

Note : Both approaches have pros and cons and you can decide on their feasibility based on you application scope.

GWT-RPC is widely used if it is complete end to end java on client and server.

GWT-JSON is used more often when fetching data from non java server.